# Vehicle detection and tracking via OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I'm trying to use YOLOv3 along with OpenCV to detect and track vehicles from some drone footage. I'm aiming to have the program identify between cars and trucks, return a total count, and, most importantly, track where a vehicle enters the video frame and exits it.

Here's an example of what the video looks like:

[image]

I'm running the following code but I get a confidence of 0.00. I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo 
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3-spp.weights", "yolov3-spp.cfg")

# Get the names of all the layers in the network
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()

# Get the indices of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
output_layer_indices = net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()


# Get the names of the output layers using the indices

output_layers = []
for i in output_layer_indices:
  output_layers.append(layer_names[i-1])

# Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("small-mud.mp4")

# Get the video writer initialized to save the output video
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))

print(f"Frame dimensions are {frame_width} by {frame_height} px");
print(f"OUT IS: {type(out)}")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    height, width, channels = img.shape

    # Detecting objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    
    #print("Detecting...")
    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)

    # Showing informations on the screen
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    for inp in outs:
        for detection in inp:
            #print("INNER LOOP...")
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            #print(confidence) #0.0
            if confidence > 0.5:
                # Object detected
                print("OBJECT DETECTED!")
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
    
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 2)

    # Write the frame into the output file
    out.write(img)

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried using different YOLOv3 models and settled on spp due to its high mAP. I tried running the pretrained model on my video, but don't get any matches.

Comment: can you test your code in different images with bigger vehicles (not drone perspective)? If it is working there, then you might have to train your own yolo for this kind of domain.

Comment: Can you download into zip file and attach in your question?